# Video upload to Heroku with Paperclip - How to make thumbnails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video, heroku, paperclip

I've just added video uploading with paperclip to a Rails 3 app I have on Heroku. It works fine but I don't know how to generate thumbnails for the videos.  I guess I should use one of the video processing add-ons in heroku?

Any recommendations for which are easiest to connect to Paperclip?

Comment: You already pointed out that you're aware of several services that do what you need. You should probably just take a look at the offerings and see what works best for your application.

Comment: Yes, thank you corey, it had occured to me to investigate the options.  A specific recommendation is always a helpful timesaver though.  That's why i asked.

Comment: These types of questions are not allowed. See the FAQ under “What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?” — http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: He is just looking for advice. Or more specifically, recommendations from other devs who have had experience in this field. I don't really see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We currently use the Zencoder encoding service to encode video uploads. Which is great, because their service provides [thumbnail generation](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails) on video files.

I would advise doing any resource intensive processes, such as encoding, outside the web app. As this can take an entire HTTP Request handler (or in your case a web dyno). Sure you can request for more web dynos. But these are expensive.

An alternative option is to do the processing in the background. But such tasks would be better off outside the web server. This is where an API service like Zencoder comes well.

Here's a set of instructions to get you [started](https://github.com/zencoder/zencoder-rb).

Another alternative is [Panda Stream](http://www.pandastream.com/). Which Heroku does offer as an addon. Both Panda Stream and Zencoder will do what you need. Both also go on different price models. Unfortunately, I cannot give you any more info on Panda, since I haven't used them.

As far as which uploader to use. Paperclip will do the job fine. I am guessing, since you are using Heroku, and you are uploading to Amazon S3. On our environment, we are using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

Comment: Thanks Christian.  Yes, i'm uploading to S3 with paperclip.  It just occurred to me that all of our video content is going to be uploaded from iphone, so the iphone should be able to send me the thumbnail along with the video.  But i'll look at zencoder.  Cheers